# Automating the permissions of login/users in sql server to another Login/user by Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, authentication

Automating the Process of Duplicating permissions from login/user to another Login/user by Stored Procedure or some automated process

Test Cases:

```
Create Login2/user like Login1/user for all databases 
Create Login2/user like Login1/user for single database
Mirror Login2/user like Login1/user for all databases 
Mirror Login2/user like Login1/user for single database
Augment Login2/user permissions from Login1/user for all databases
Augment Login2/user permissions from Login1/user for single database
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[USP_Duplicate_Login]')
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1
        )
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Duplicate_Login]

GO
```

/*This Stored Procedure will Copy the Server Permissioms(Server role Membership, Custom Server Roles and Server Permissions) from 
    @EXISTING_USER TO  @LOGIN_TO_BE_DUPLICATED*/

```
--@EXISTING_login- from which Server Permissions will be Copied
--@USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED-To the login, Permissions are Copied

  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Duplicate_Login]
  @LOGIN_TO_BE_DUPLICATED sysname ,
  @existing_login sysname 
AS 

BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @Return int;
```

-- Query to handle server roles
     BEGIN TRAN;
    DECLARE cursRoleMemberSQL CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
    FOR

```
 SELECT 'EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = ''' + @LOGIN_TO_BE_DUPLICATED+                                                                         ''', @rolename = ''' + R.name + ''';' AS 'SQL'
    FROM sys.server_role_members AS RM JOIN sys.server_principals AS L ON RM.member_principal_id = L.principal_id
    JOIN sys.server_principals AS R ON RM.role_principal_id = R.principal_id WHERE L.name = @existing_login;

OPEN cursRoleMemberSQL;

FETCH FROM cursRoleMemberSQL INTO @SQL;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
      PRINT @SQL;
      EXECUTE @Return = sp_executesql @SQL;

IF (@Return <> 0)
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRAN;
RAISERROR('Error encountered assigning role memberships.', 16, 1);
CLOSE cursRoleMembersSQL;
DEALLOCATE cursRoleMembersSQL;
RETURN(1);
END

FETCH NEXT FROM cursRoleMemberSQL INTO @SQL;
END;

CLOSE cursRoleMemberSQL;
DEALLOCATE cursRoleMemberSQL;
    --Query to handle Server Permissions
DECLARE cursServerPermissionSQL CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT CASE P.state WHEN 'W' 
THEN 'USE master; GRANT ' + P.permission_name + ' TO [' + @LOGIN_TO_BE_DUPLICATED + '] WITH GRANT OPTION;'
ELSE 
'USE master;  ' + P.state_desc + ' ' + P.permission_name + ' TO [' + @LOGIN_TO_BE_DUPLICATED + '];'   END AS 'SQL'
FROM sys.server_permissions AS P JOIN sys.server_principals AS L ON P.grantee_principal_id = L.principal_id
WHERE L.name = @existing_login AND P.class = 100 AND P.type <> 'COSQ'

UNION ALL

SELECT CASE P.state WHEN 'W' 
THEN 
'USE master; GRANT ' + P.permission_name + ' ON LOGIN::[' + L2.name + '] TO [' + @LOGIN_TO_BE_DUPLICATED + '] WITH GRANT OPTION;' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
ELSE 
'USE master; ' + P.state_desc + ' ' + P.permission_name + ' ON LOGIN::[' + L2.name + '] TO [' + @LOGIN_TO_BE_DUPLICATED + '];' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
END AS 'SQL'
FROM sys.server_permissions AS P JOIN sys.server_principals AS L ON P.grantee_principal_id = L.principal_id
JOIN sys.server_principals AS L2 ON P.major_id = L2.principal_id WHERE L.name = @existing_login AND P.class = 101

OPEN cursServerPermissionSQL;

FETCH FROM cursServerPermissionSQL INTO @SQL;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
PRINT @SQL;
EXEC @Return = sp_executesql @SQL;

IF (@Return <> 0)
BEGIN
 ROLLBACK TRAN;
 RAISERROR('Error encountered adding server level permissions', 16, 1);
 CLOSE cursServerPermissionSQL;
 DEALLOCATE cursServerPermissionSQL;
 RETURN(1);
END

FETCH NEXT FROM cursServerPermissionSQL INTO @SQL;
END;

CLOSE cursServerPermissionSQL;
DEALLOCATE cursServerPermissionSQL;

COMMIT TRAN;

END;
GO


For Duplicating User Permissions



IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[USP_DB_PERMISSIONS]')
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1
        )
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_DB_PERMISSIONS]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_DB_PERMISSIONS]  ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


/*This Stored Procedure will generate the DB Permissioms(Database Role Membership, Custom Database Roles, Database Permissions, Object Permissions, Schema Permissions, User Permissions from 
@DUPLICATE_USER TO @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED*/
--@DBNAME-Database Name from which Database Permissions has to be Copied
--@Duplicate_USER- From which User Permissions will be Copied
--@USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED--To the User, Permissions are generated to

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_DB_PERMISSIONS] @DBNAME SYSNAME, @DUPLICATE_USER SYSNAME, @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL1 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL2 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL3 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL4 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL5 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL6 VARCHAR(MAX)




  SET @SQL = 'USE [' + @DBName + ']; IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals 
                         WHERE name = ''' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED + ''')
                 BEGIN
                   CREATE USER [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '] FROM LOGIN [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED + '];
                 END;';
  EXEC (@SQL)


--Database Role Membership

SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT '' ALTER ROLE  [''+r.name+'']  ADD  MEMBER  [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  +'] ;''AS ''' + @DBName + ' Database Role Membership''
    FROM [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_principals AS U
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_role_members AS RM
        ON U.principal_id = RM.member_principal_id
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_principals AS R
        ON RM.role_principal_id = R.principal_id
    WHERE U.name = ''' + @DUPLICATE_USER + ''';';

    EXEC (@SQL1);

--Database Permissions
SET @SQL2='SELECT CASE [state]
       WHEN ''W'' THEN ''GRANT '' + permission_name + '' ON DATABASE::[' 
         + @DBName + '] TO [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '] WITH GRANT OPTION;'' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
       ELSE state_desc + '' '' + permission_name + '' ON DATABASE::[' 
         + @DBNAME + '] TO [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '];'' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
       END AS ''' + @DBName + ' Database Permissions''
    FROM [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_permissions AS P
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_principals AS U
        ON P.grantee_principal_id = U.principal_id
    WHERE class = 0
      AND P.[type] <> ''CO''
      AND U.name = ''' + @DUPLICATE_USER + ''';';

    EXEC (@SQL2);

--Schema Permissions

SET @SQL3 = '
    SELECT CASE [state]
       WHEN ''W'' THEN ''GRANT '' + permission_name + '' ON SCHEMA::['' 
         + S.name + ''] TO [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '] WITH GRANT OPTION;'' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
       ELSE state_desc + '' '' + permission_name + '' ON SCHEMA::['' 
         + S.name + ''] TO [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '];'' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
       END AS ''' + @DBName + ' Schema Permissions''
    FROM [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_permissions AS P
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_principals AS U
        ON P.grantee_principal_id = U.principal_id
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.schemas AS S
        ON S.schema_id = P.major_id
    WHERE class = 3
      AND U.name = ''' + @DUPLICATE_USER + ''';';

    exec (@SQL3);

--Object Permissions
SET @SQL4 = '
    SELECT CASE [state]
       WHEN ''W'' THEN ''GRANT '' + permission_name + '' ON OBJECT:: ['' +s.name+ ''].['' 
         + O.name + ''] TO [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '] WITH GRANT OPTION;'' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
       ELSE state_desc + '' '' + permission_name + '' ON OBJECT::[''+s.name+''].['' 
         + O.name + ''] TO [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '];'' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
       END AS ''' + @DBName + ' Object Permissions''
    FROM [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_permissions AS P
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_principals AS U
        ON P.grantee_principal_id = U.principal_id
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.objects AS O
        ON O.object_id = P.major_id
      Join [' + @DBName + '].sys.schemas AS S
       ON O.schema_id= s.schema_id
    WHERE class = 1
      AND U.name = ''' + @DUPLICATE_USER + '''
      AND P.major_id > 0
      AND P.minor_id = 0';

exec (@SQL4)

-- Object Column Permissions
SET @SQL5 = '
    SELECT CASE [state]
       WHEN ''W'' THEN ''GRANT '' + permission_name + '' ON OBJECT::['' +s.name+ ''].['' 
         + O.name + ''] ('' + C.name + '') TO [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '] WITH GRANT OPTION;'' 
         COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
       ELSE state_desc + '' '' + permission_name + '' ON OBJECT::['' +s.name+ ''].['' 
         + O.name + ''] ('' + C.name + '') TO [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '];'' 
         COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
       END AS ''' + @DBName + ' Object Column Permissions ''
    FROM [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_permissions AS P
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_principals AS U
        ON P.grantee_principal_id = U.principal_id
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.objects AS O
        ON O.object_id = P.major_id
      Join [' + @DBName + '].sys.schemas AS S
       ON O.schema_id= s.schema_id
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.columns AS C
        ON C.column_id = P.minor_id AND o.object_id = C.object_id
    WHERE class = 1
      AND U.name = ''' + @DUPLICATE_USER + '''
      AND P.major_id > 0
      AND P.minor_id > 0;'

     exec (@SQL5);
--Permissions On Users
SET @SQL6 = '
    SELECT CASE [state]
       WHEN ''W'' THEN ''GRANT '' + permission_name + '' ON USER::['' 
         + U2.name + ''] TO [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '] WITH GRANT OPTION;'' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
       ELSE state_desc + '' '' + permission_name + '' ON USER::['' 
         + U2.name + ''] TO [' + @USER_TO_BE_DUPLICATED  + '];'' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
       END AS ''' + @DBName + ' Permissions On Users''
    FROM [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_permissions AS P
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_principals AS U
        ON P.grantee_principal_id = U.principal_id
      JOIN [' + @DBName + '].sys.database_principals AS U2
        ON U2.principal_id = P.major_id
    WHERE class = 4
      AND U.name = ''' + @DUPLICATE_USER + ''';';

  exec (@SQL6);


  END;


GO
```